# One neural network per target or one neutral network for many targets?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have about 20 targets in a model I'd like to try to forecast, these each take many features (the same ~100 features and use different formula/relations etc. observed/simulated).

Does it make sense to use one neural network predicting many targets or should there always only be one target per neural network? Or is there a way to divide up most 'commonly related' (e.g. correlated) targets and have e.g. 4 neural networks 5 targets each?

Comment: what is the type of target ? Categorical, Continuous ? It will be greated if you can name some of targets .

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to make one bigger network with 20 neurons in the output layer so you can exploit the whole dataset size and the network will create  better data representation on middle layers and generalize better.

It is also a better idea because, even if you have multiple NNs, then you have to figure out a way to use the correct one for a given input and that step requires further optimization and may lead to additional errors

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to make one large neural network and for the `output` layer you should use `20` neurons (number of possible outcomes) and you should use a `softmax` activation function.
Your model can look something like this.

```
input_dim = X_train.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_dim=input_dim))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
               optimizer='adam', 
               metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you clarify why you recommend softmax?

Comment: The output of a Softmax activation function is a vector with probabilities of each possible outcome. So you will obtain a list of the probabilities for each neuron ( corrisponding to each class ) and the class with the highest probability will be your output.